# Storing an element into an object to use as a click handler doesn't work correctly (jQuery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works correctly:

```
function clickHandler(){
    $(config.container).find('.'+config.play).on('click',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

However when I place the element into a variable for easier use, it doesn't work:

```
var element={
    play:$(config.container).find('.'+config.play)
}

function clickHandler(){
    element.play.on('click',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

Am I doing something incorrect here? Thanks.

Comment: `element.play` grabs the DOM element when the element variable is defined, whereas `clickHandler()` doesn't grab the DOM element until the function is invoked. It's a timing issue. Either use event delegation, or grab the element after it has been created

Comment: Yes. This is correct. I struggled with this for two days and only realized it immediately after posting my question so that I can look stupid to the world. I declared the object before the elements were created. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it always work like that? `;)` Glad you figured it out. I posted an answer with an example of event delegation, which I believe to be the best and simplest solution for what you're trying to do. No need for `element.play` and no need for your `clickHandler` function to attach the event.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to access elements before they exist. In your top code example, the DOM elements are not being searched for until the `clickHandler()` function is executed. Whereas in the bottom code example, it is trying to find the DOM elements immediately, and presumably, in your case, they don't exist yet.

Here are a couple alternatives to solve your issue:

**1) Event Delegation**

```
$(config.container).on('click', '.' + config.play,function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

**2) Turn `element.play` into a function**

```
var element={
    play: function () {
        return $(config.container).find('.'+config.play);
    }
}

function clickHandler() {
    element.play().on('click', ...);
}
```